# how to remove a + (plus) mark from a String using a regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I Need to remove the plus (+) from a String using regex in java.

`+876755444` should be able to remove `+` then it should display like `876755444`.

I was trying to do this and new to regex as well.
Can anybody tell me how to do this.

Comment: Please share what you tried till now ??

Comment: *I was trying to do this*, we would like to see what you tried

Comment: this won't need a regex.

Comment: I guess that's what you need : **myString.replaceAll("\\+","");**

Comment: If the '+' is only at the start of the String (your input looks like a phone number), you can simply use `startsWith/charAt(0)` and `substring`.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I need to confirm that should only be a phone number. It doesn't include non numeric values. I'm sorry coz I haven't mentioned that in the question. I need to do all this withing a single regex.

Comment: Your comment still doesn't explain why you must use regex. Why you want to avoid using method which will replace `+` literal without regex? Can you give us example which would explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "+876755444"; 

System.out.println(s.replace("+", ""));
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer of @nafas should be correct:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\+","");
```

Answer (score 4):

This would remove all non-numeric chars.

```
string.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```